# Como obter todas as postagens da API REST do WordPress?

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, api, rest

per_page retorna posts no intervalo de 1 até 100, porem precisava retornar 500. Como obter todas as postagens da API REST do WordPress?

Comment: A resposta do @Raphael Nikson não resolveu o seu problema?

Answer (score 0):

se você utilizar o &filter[posts_per_page]=-1 você retorna todos..